# Does Mac OS have a way to create an anonymous file mapping?

Tags: macos, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

In the UNIX world, the standard way to create a file mapping object backed by RAM or the pagefile rather than a disk file is to call `shm_open`.  This creates a memory mapping with a name, and returns a file handle that you can pass to `mmap`.

The problem is that it creates a name.  It would be nice if I could create an anonymous memory mapping.  This would solve two problems:

1. It would avoid problems where two instances of the same program may stomp on each other's mapped files.
2. If the program crashes or otherwise suddenly terminates, it would not leave the shared memory object around.  Calling `shm_unlink` immediately after `shm_open` is one possibility, but this leaves a small window in which a sudden termination would leave the object around until the next reboot.

In Linux, there is `memfd_create` to solve this problem.  Similarly, Windows allows passing a null name to `CreateFileMappingW` to create an anonymous mapping.

Is there an equivalent for Mac OS?

Comment: I *think* you just do `mmap()` with `MAP_ANON` and `fd=-1` - but I have been wrong many times before:-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Not that simple, I'm afraid.  Such mappings cannot be inherited as file handles, nor can you use FD passing to give the handle to another process.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't realise from your question that you needed to do that.

Comment: @Myria, you should put such requirements in the question. Also, does the mechanism for inheritance or passing have to be file descriptors? The Mach `vm_*` functions can create memory mappings and then set them to be inherited and/or pass them to other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a file with `open` and then immediately remove it from the filesystem with `unlink`. The file descriptor will remain open, and the file itself will stay alive until its last descriptor is closed. This works if you need a file descriptor to share between processes, and it appears to solve the two problems that you listed.

Alternatively, passing both `MAP_ANON` and `MAP_SHARED` to `mmap` creates a shared memory region that is not backed by any file but that is shared between this process and all of its forks. However, like any memory mapping, it is deleted on `exec`.

Comment: Calling `open` would violate requirement 2 - if sudden termination occurs between `open` and `unlink`, it would leave a file around.  As in comments above, I forgot to mention that it also needs to be an FD.

Comment: @Myria, it seems to me that you phrased the problem in a way that the only possible solution is `memfd_create` (that is: it has to be a file descriptor, and it can't show on the file system), which macOS doesn't have.

Comment: Then the answer is that it is impossible, and I could then close it.